# Confusion about Dirac mass term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, dirac-equation, spinors

In chiral basis, $\psi=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_L\\
\psi_R
\end{pmatrix}$ and therefore, $\overline\psi=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi^\dagger_L & \psi^\dagger_R
\end{pmatrix}\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi^\dagger_R & \psi^\dagger_L
\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, by matrix multiplication, $\overline \psi \psi=\psi^\dagger_R \psi_L+\psi^\dagger_L \psi_R$.

Again using chiral projection operators it can be shown that, $\overline\psi\psi=\bar\psi_R \psi_L+\bar\psi_L \psi_R$.

Therefore, these two relations suggest that, we can also write, $\overline\psi$ as $\overline\psi=\begin{pmatrix}
\bar\psi_R & \bar\psi_L
\end{pmatrix}$.

1. Am I right? If yes, how can I show $\overline\psi=\begin{pmatrix}
   \bar\psi_R & \bar\psi_L
   \end{pmatrix}$starting from the $\overline\psi=\psi^\dagger\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}
   \psi^\dagger_R & \psi^\dagger_L
   \end{pmatrix}$? Moreover, this implies:

   $$\psi^\dagger_R \psi_L+\psi^\dagger_L \psi_R=\bar\psi_R \psi_L+\bar\psi_L \psi_R$$
2. Am I right? If yes, how can I prove the last relation starting from either side of it?

Comment: On the chance to sound ignorant, but what does $\bar{\psi}_R$ mean? Also, can you give a reference where the claim is proven?

Comment: @nephente $\bar\psi_R=\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}\psi$ and $\bar\psi_L=\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}\psi$. I didn't get which claim are you talking about. Can you please mention it specifically?

Comment: Ok. I meant $\bar{\Psi}\Psi=\bar{\Psi}_R\Psi_L+\bar{\Psi}_L\Psi_R$

Comment: @nephente- the proof goes as follows: $\bar\psi_L\psi_R+\bar\psi_R\psi_L=\bar\psi(\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2})(\frac{1+\gamma^5}{2})\psi+\bar\psi(\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2})(\frac{1-\gamma^5}{2})\psi=\bar\psi\psi $. Intermediate steps are trivial to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusion is with notation since, unfortunately, there are two common ways to denote projected spinors. One form is to write:
\begin{equation}
\psi \equiv \left( \begin{array}{c} 
\psi _L  \\  
\psi _R  
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation} 
In this notation $ \psi _L $ and $ \psi _R $ are two component Weyl spinors. However, a second notation is also used where 
\begin{equation} 
\psi _L \equiv P _L \psi , \quad \psi _R \equiv P _R \psi 
\end{equation} 
and $ P _{L/R } $ are the projection operators. Now $ \psi _L $ and $ \psi _R $ are four component spinors with a zero value for two the components.

In the first notation (where $ \psi _{ L/ R } $ are Weyl spinors) the Dirac term takes the form,
\begin{equation} 
m \bar{\psi} \psi = m \left( \psi _R ^\dagger \psi _L + h.c. \right) 
\end{equation} 
and in the second (where $ \psi _{ L/R} $ are four component objects) it takes the form,
\begin{equation} 
m \bar{\psi} \psi = m \left( \overline{ \psi _R}  \psi _L + h.c. \right) 
\end{equation} 
Its just a matter of convention and the end result is the same.

Comment: @ JeffDror -Therefore, I think I can also write $\bar\psi=\begin{pmatrix} \bar \psi_R & \bar\psi_L\\ \end{pmatrix}$, if I consider all $\bar\psi_{L,R}$ as 4-component rows. Am I right?

Comment: @Roopam, yes that is one way to write it. Though its a bit sloppy. What we really mean is in four-component notation: $\overline{\psi}=\overline{\psi_L}+\overline{\psi_R}$

Comment: @ JeffDror - Okay. I understand. Your answers are very helpful. I was indeed confused by the notations.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you like them.

Comment: The notation in which $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ denote 2-component spinors suggest that there is a $2\times 2$chirality projection operator. However, as far as I know, there is no such thing and the chirality projection operators are always $4\times 4$ matrices $\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\gamma^5)$ @JeffDror